# Expected stopping time for N dimensional lattice random walk

Tags: probability, random-walk

Is there a general formula for this given the boundary? I saw how optional stopping theorem is used to derive the expected stopping time for 1 dimension, $\mathbb{E}(T)=ab$ if walk is between $-a,b$, but when I tried to use the same method for a 2 dimensional box it doesn't work, there are more probability terms than the number of constraining equations (in 1 dimension there are 2 probability terms and 2 linear equations constraining them).

What is the method for calculating $\mathbb{E}(T)$? in 2D, 3D, and higher?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "there are more probability terms than the number of constraining equations". Could you elaborate on what you tried?

Comment: In 1D $\mathbb{E}(S_T)=0=\mathbb{E}(S^2_T-T)$, and $\mathbb{E}(S_T)=0$ together with $\mathbb{P}(S_T=-a)+\mathbb{P}(S_T=b)=1$ gives 2 simultaneously equations for the probability terms, so $\mathbb{E}(S^2_T)=\mathbb{E}(T)$ can be calculated. But in 2D there are too many probability terms for the $X_T$ and $Y_T$ stopped coordinates (these are the analogues of $S_T$ in 2D). How do you calculate stopping time in 2D for a box, and more general boundries?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me whether you're looking for a closed-form solution or whether you just want to know how to calculate them. If you just want to calculate them, the equations at each lattice point and the zero boundary conditions together give you exactly the number of equations you need. Whether that leads to a nice closed form depends on your domain.

Comment: How do you calculate? Can you give example for the box with 4 corners $(a,b),(a,-b),(-a,b),(-a,-b)$.

Comment: Whatever your domain, if you have $k$ contiguous non-absorbing sites, you have $k$ variables (the expected stopping time starting from each site), and you have $k$ linear equations for them that express the fact that the expected stopping time from a site is the average of the expected stopping times from the adjacent sites, plus $1$ (where the adjacent absorbing sites have expected stopping time $0$). So you can solve that system of linear equations.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. By $k$ sites, do you means the points on the boundary? The random walk starts at the origin, so what do you mean by "expected stopping time starting from each site"? I've been thinking about this and tried to find $\mathbb{P}(X_T=x_j,Y_T=y_j)$, where $(x_j,y_j)$ are the points of the boundary, but I don't know how to get as many equations as there are points, and even if I do I don't know if the matrix is invertible to guarantee a unique solution. Can you be more precise on what you mean? Thanks.